# Student Registration System

Tags: java, jdbc

This application is a "Student Registration System" using JDBC with Oracle as part of our school project. It works as it stands right now.

Questions:

1. What is a better way to structure the project? Why?
2. Any 'crimes' committed in the code?

Details:

- I've decided to make the interface as a web service/page instead of a swing application.
- I'm using Tomcat 7.0, jTable.org jquery based table, JSP, Java.

The current files in the project:

- DBInterface.java
- StudentInterface.java
- Students.java - Acts as the model interfacing with the database using JDBC
- StudentsAjax.jsp - Acts as the view providing data and services to the HTML client 
  index.html

Important parts of the files:

**`DBInterface`**

```
package models;

public interface DBInterface {      
    static final String dburl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@";
    static final String dbuser = "xxx";
    static final String dbpass = "xxx";
}
```

**`StudentInterface`**

```
package models;

import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public interface StudentsInterface extends DBInterface {

    public int createStudent(String sid, String firstName, String lastName, String status, double gpa,  String email);

    public List<JSONObject> retrieveStudent(String sid);

...........

}
```

**`Students`**

```
package models;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Students implements StudentsInterface {

    /*
     * Method creates a Student entry into the table.
     * @Returns 1 if successfull. 0 otherwise.
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see models.StudentsInterface#createStudent(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public int createStudent(String sid, String firstName, String lastName, String status, double gpa,  String email) {

        int retVal = 0;

        try {
            // Connection to Oracle server
            OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
            ds.setURL(dburl);
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection(dbuser, dbpass);

              //Insert
              PreparedStatement insert = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into students VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

              // Input other values 
              insert.setString(1, sid);
              insert.setString(2, firstName);
              insert.setString(3, lastName);
              insert.setString(4, status);
              insert.setDouble(5, gpa);
              insert.setString(6, email);             

              // execute the update
              insert.executeUpdate();

            // close the result set, statement, and the connection
            conn.close();
            retVal = 1;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n*** SQLException caught ***\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n*** other Exception caught ***\n");
        }

        return  retVal;
    }


    //--------------------------------------
    @Override
    public List<JSONObject> retrieveStudent(String sid) {

        List<JSONObject> t = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        try {
            // Connection to Oracle server
            OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
            ds.setURL(dburl);
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection(dbuser, dbpass);

            // Query
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("\n*** Executing");

            String query = "SELECT * FROM students";

            if(!sid.equals("ALL")) 
                query += " WHERE sid = '" + sid + "' ";

            // Save result
            ResultSet rset;
            rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("\n*** Done");
            // determine the number of columns in each row of the result set
            ResultSetMetaData rsetMeta = rset.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsetMeta.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("\n*** Retrieved Student Count is 


            //insert result into a List
            while (rset.next()) {
                JSONObject e = new JSONObject();

                //loop through columns
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {

                     String key = rsetMeta.getColumnName(i);
                     String value = rset.getString(i);

                     //Convert First char to upper case
                     key = key.toLowerCase();
            key =toString(key.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+key.substring(1);

                     e.put(key,value);

                }

                 t.add(e);
            }

            // close the result set, statement, and the connection
            rset.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n*** SQLException caught ***\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n*** other Exception caught ***\n");
        }

        return t;
    }
....
....
....
}
```

**`StudentsAjax`**

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="models.*" %>
<% String incomingAction = (String)request.getParameter("action");  %>
<%
    StudentsInterface si = new Students();
    JSONObject cover = new JSONObject();

    //Decide what to perform based on incoming action.
    //-------------------- LIST
    if(incomingAction.equals("list")) {
        //Prepare JSON output
        cover.put("Result","OK");
        cover.put("Records", listStudents("ALL"));
    }
    else //-------------------- CREATE
    if(incomingAction.equals("create")) {


        //Retrieve result
        int reply = si.createStudent(
                    (String)request.getParameter("Sid")
                    ,(String)request.getParameter("Firstname")
                    ,(String)request.getParameter("Lastname")
                    ,(String)request.getParameter("Status")
                    ,(String)request.getParameter("Email")
                );

        //Prepare JSON output
        cover.put("Result","OK");
    cover.put("Record", listStudents((String)request.getParameter("Sid")).get(0)  );
    }
    else //-------------------- UPDATE
.....
.....
.....


    //Output in the JSON format.
    out.println(cover.toString());

%>
<%!


// -------------------------------- Functions
List<JSONObject> listStudents(String id) {
    StudentsInterface si = new Students();
    List<JSONObject> t;

    //Retrieve result
    if(id.equals("ALL")) {
        t = si.showAllStudents();
    }
    else {

        t = si.retrieveStudent(id);
    }

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Follow layered architecture. [Read about Model-View-Controller pattern.](http://www.cmjackson.net/2010/01/18/mvc-and-n-layer-architecture/) (This should eliminate most of your design issues so I won't specify each one of them here)
2. Externalize environment specific entries like dburl, dbuser and dbpassword by [creating a JDBC DataSource in tomcat. You should also pool database connections.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) This should eliminate the need for `DBInterface`.
3. Use Checked (like StudentNotFoundException etc.) and Unchecked exceptions. Here are the [guidelines](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

Comment: Thanks Pangea for commenting on and pointing out good resources for improving the design of the system.

Answer (score 2):

The first 'crime' is a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. You are using a `PreparedStatement` when inserting, which is great. You avoided the problem there. But this is a problem:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM students";
if(!sid.equals("ALL")) 
    query += " WHERE sid = '" + sid + "' ";
```

If the `sid` parameter comes from outside the system (as it does above), it can be anything, including a maliciously crafted string that could cause damage to the system. The simple solution is to build the query using parameter placeholders and use a `PreparedStatement` here as well.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM students";
if(!sid.equals("ALL")) 
    query += " WHERE sid = ?";
```

---

The second 'crime' is the unsafe closing of database resources. Each resource should be closed in a `finally` block to ensure that it is properly released, even in the event that an exception occurs while working with the resource.

For example, given this code:

```
Connection conn = ds.getConnection(dbuser, dbpass);
// do some work using the connection (what if an exception occurs here?)
conn.close();
```

The connection will not be closed if an exception occurs between opening and closing the connection. To ensure the connection is always closed, use something like this:

```
Connection conn = ds.getConnection(dbuser, dbpass);
try {
    // do some work using the connection
}
finally {
    conn.close(); // this will be called even if an exception occurs in the try block
}
```

If you are using Java 7, check out the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. The above code can be simplified to this:

```
try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection(dbuser, dbpass)) {
    // do some work using the connection
} // connection will automatically be closed here
```

This also goes for prepared statements, result sets, and any other type of resource that might need to be closed/released.

---

`createStudent` is declared to return an `int` of 1 if successful, 0 otherwise. It seems like a `boolean` would better represent the possible outcomes. Having said that, it might be even better to throw an exception in the event of failure.

---

The `retrieveStudent` function is confusing. The name and argument imply that it will retrieve a single student by an sid, but the return type implies it will return multiple. It is not obvious that you can call it in a 'special' way to get all students. I would recommend splitting this into 2 separate functions:

```
public JSONObject retrieveStudent(String sid) { ... }
public List<JSONObject> retrieveStudents() { ... }
```

---

JSP files are generally used for presentation and very limited logic. It is more common to put request handling logic in a servlet (or controller in a MVC framework), then render the presentation using a JSP. In this case, there really is no presentation, so all of that code could be in a servlet.

---

You should not need to cast the `request.getParameter()` calls to a `String`. They are already declared to return a `String`.

Comment: Thanks Joe for Pointing out the security issue and commenting on the general coding standards ! mucha gracis !